# How to use split with a column where each cell's integer is stored as an array

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am trying to get a script going in google sheets that  takes data from a specific column (this column is quantity, and each integer is separated by a comma.

I need to use the split function to ignore the commas and get the sum of all numbers in a cell, but I also need them stored in some form  of array in order to iterate through the entire column (in my instance its column C)

I have been looking for answers of how to achieve this but none seem to have both the split function while also getting the sum for each cell.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get you started with Google App Script here is a simple example.

A few notes on my coding style.  I rarely use global variables and I try to limit the scope of variables within my function by using `let`.

I always use a try{} catch(){} block to display any error messages, whether it is server side or client side dialog or web app.

The + before total below coerces total to be a number.

[image]

Code.gs

```
function test() {
  try {
    // I just run this from the script editor but it could be assigned to a menu option
    // get the active spreadsheet
    let spread = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    // get Sheet1
    let sheet = spread.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
    // get the values on the sheet as a 2D array 
    // [["Values","Sum"],["1,2,3",""],["4,5,6,7,8",""],["9,10",""]]
    let data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
    data.shift(); // remove the headers
    // now loop through each row of values and sum up the values
    // I'm using the arrow version of a javascript function
    let results = data.map( row => {
        let values = row[0].split(",");  //  split the comma delimited string
        let sum = values.reduce( (total,value) => +total+parseInt(value) );  // note the + before total
        return [sum];
      }
    );
    // now we put into the second column
    sheet.getRange(2,2,results.length,1).setValues(results);
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

References

- [Spreadsheet Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/)
- [Array.shift()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_shift.asp)
- [Array.map()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_map.asp)
- [String.split()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp)
- [Array.reduce()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_reduce.asp)
- [javascript Arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Comment: This is an amazing block of code. it seems to work like a switch statement but for error checking?

I tried changing your code around to only target C2:C (Only the C column and add all integers in each cell and iterate to the next object but nothing seems to happen. debug log says it completes but no result. Is .replace() or .push needed to replace a cells value?

Comment: The `.map()` and `.reduce()` functions are more like `for` loops.  If your values are in column C you could use row[2].split(",").  Ths command `sheet.getRange(2,2,results.length,1).setValues(results);` puts the summed values back to the spreadsheet in column B.  You could change it to whatever you want.

Comment: sheet.getRange(2,2) seems to run the code in column B instead of column C.  when I switch getRange to (3,3) Which is strange because I thought javascript starts at 0  when counting rows/columns. 

Besides that though when any column is selected its filling the cells with #NUM, is that because its expecting an integer but finding a string?
https://pastebin.com/T8Dj9k0m

Comment: No javascript arrays are 0 based index but getRange()/setRange() are 1 for row 1 and 1 for column 1.  Perhaps update your code so I can see what you are doiing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use reduce method, see below :

```js
myfunction(severalRange){
  var result =0
  for(var cell in severalRange){
    var value = cell.getValue(); // sample value is  C1: "1,2,3,10" C2 : "1"
    var arrayValue = value.split(",");// [ '1', '2', '3', '10' ]
    arrayValue = arrayValue.map( item =>parseInt(item)) //[ 1, 2, 3, 10 ]

    // Use reduce method of array, see : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce
    // in other word : iterate over an array, starting at initial = 0 and do previous value + currentValue 
    const initialValue = 0;
    const sumWithInitial = arrayValue.reduce(
      (previousValue, currentValue) => previousValue + currentValue,
      initialValue
    );
  
    result = result + sumWithInitial
    console.log(sumWithInitial); // 16 then 17
    }
  return result
}
```

Feel free to ask additional question

Comment: I seem to be running into a typeError: value.split is not a function. if C1 is called by itself its fine but if I change it to C2 or C2:C for the entire column I get a syntax error but its clearly splitting a string. here is what I got

https://pastebin.com/h9xuS6VM

Comment: Got it, then you have to do a for(var cell in value)

Comment: and acces cell value ussing cell.getValue()

Comment: It runs without any errors but I guess I was hoping the delmited quantity values in the entire column would get replaced with the final sum of each cell added up together.

As it stands my C cell  has each cell like such:

1,1,1,1,
Next cell 
4,1,4,6
Next cell.
I feel like im missing something really simple to make this work for my case but I am just not sure what it is.
|
https://pastebin.com/g7f3TiA5

Comment: @Drac, I made a mistake in the code above, it's correct now. Could you try if it match your expectation ?